# Rails 4 - Difference between //= require jquery.ui.all or use a CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I was wondering what the difference or advantages between the following is:

insert `//= require jquery.ui.all` in the file `application.js`

AND

insert `javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.10.4.min"` into the
    layout (`application.html.erb`).

In my point of view, I can see appeal in both of the propositions, because the first one does a lots of requests while the second one includes all in just one request !

Comment: Deploy your code and you probably will want to use the first one...
Once in production, your code gets 'versioned', so your relative paths get all messed up if you use <script...>, but with //= require, rails will handle that for you.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake in my question, I've edited. It was not a relative path.

Comment: Ah!Ok. So use a CDN! Is better for your server, why not?
For dev is usually not so cool, you want the thing served fast, but in production, I think the CDN is better for the end user since browsers cut the number of downloads you can make for a single domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edited the question and now you are not using a CDN on the example so that may be misleading for what you want.

Anyway, you have 3 options (maybe more? I don't know): inside the manifest with a //require, in your assets path with a link tag or in a CDN, what to use depends on you

Inside the manifest:
Rails compiles the manifest (usually application.js), puts everything inside the final .js file so you have, at the end, only one request to get all the javascript for your site.

Outside the manifest, with a link tag:
This is usefull if you have something that is loaded few times and is heavy. If you don't need that thing on every page on your site and is heavy you can have that outside the main application.js and load it only when needed.
You need to add that file to the precompile assets array on production config.

On a CDN:
This makes the site faster. You can do a limited number of request to a single site in parallel, using a CDN allows you to do some requests to your site an some to a CDN, you can make more request in parallel and also CDN's responses are usually faster.
This requires more work, you need to syn your assets with the CDN, I'm not sure if the precompilation process can do that for you (maybe there's some gem, I don't know).